# Python regular expression find first '&'

Tags: python, regex, url

```
link = "http://blog.test.com/54321&sa=U&ei=1sTFVJLfOtOC8gW0jIHYCw&ved=0CBMQFjAA"
pat = re.compile("(.*)\&(.*)")
match = re.search(pat,link)
print match.group(1)
```

the result is `http://blog.test.com/54321&sa=U&ei=1sTFVJLfOtOC8gW0jIHYCw`

But what I need is `http://blog.test.com/54321` 
How to match to result I want?
Please guide me,Thank you

Comment: This url looks malformed - is this intended?

Comment: I agree, the URL looks malformed. Usually `/54321&sa=U` would be `/54321?sa=U` (notice the `?` rather than `&` to start the parameters list).

Comment: Also, there's already a module for parsing URLs: [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse). Why roll out your own when it's already in the standard library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

without using Regex.

```
link = "http://blog.test.com/54321&sa=U&ei=1sTFVJLfOtOC8gW0jIHYCw&ved=0CBMQFjAA"

_link = link.split('&',1)
result = _link[0]

>>print result
>>'http://blog.test.com/54321'
```

Comment: You might also want to limit the split: `link.split('&', 1)`

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting that output is because of the greediness of *. To make it lazy instead:

```
link = "http://blog.test.com/54321&sa=U&ei=1sTFVJLfOtOC8gW0jIHYCw&ved=0CBMQFjAA"
pat = re.compile("(.*?)\&")
match = re.search(pat,link)
print match.group(1)
```

Notice the `?` in the new pattern.

For such a simple case however, I would recommend the built-in solution:

```
print link.split('&')[0]
```

Comment: If `&` isn't found then you end up deleting the last character of the input string with your `find` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a positive lookahead assertion.

```
pat = re.compile(r"^.*?(?=&)")
match = re.search(pat,link)
print match.group()
```

Without regex,

```
>>> link = "http://blog.test.com/54321&sa=U&ei=1sTFVJLfOtOC8gW0jIHYCw&ved=0CBMQFjAA"
>>> s = ""
>>> for i in link:
        if i == '&':
            print(s)
            break
        else:
            s += i


http://blog.test.com/54321
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

This also guarantees that if no `'&'` is found, the entire string will be returned. You won't have the issue where the result is `''`, `None`, or is otherwise not returning any part of the string.

```
>>> link = "http://blog.test.com/54321&sa=U&ei=1sTFVJLfOtOC8gW0jIHYCw&ved=0CBMQFjAA"

>>> symbolIndex = link.find('&')
>>> print link[:symbolIndex] if symbolIndex >= 0 else link

'http://blog.test.com/54321'
```

In cases like these, regular expressions aren't necessary. You can easily do the same with regular `str` methods.

Comment: There's no such thing as "void" in Python. Do you mean `None`, or maybe the empty string? It's not clear from the context what you're referring to as being "void". Anyway, your solution drops the last character from the string if `&` is not found, so it doesn't really handle that case correctly.

Comment: @DaoWen I was sloppy there. You're right. The OP had a comment posted earlier on someone else's answer where he expressed concern that if the `'&'` wasn't found, the result would be void. He really just meant `None`, but I used his terminology (lazily) to address his concerns. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution;

```
link = "http://blog.test.com/54321&sa=U&ei=1sTFVJLfOtOC8gW0jIHYCw&ved=0CBMQFjAA"
for i in link:
    if i == "&":
        ind=link.index("&")
        print (link[:ind])
        break
```

Output;

```
>>> 
http://blog.test.com/54321
>>>
```

**Or with regex**;

```
link = "http://blog.test.com/54321&sa=U&ei=1sTFVJLfOtOC8gW0jIHYCw&ved=0CBMQFjAA"
t = re.search("&",link).group()
if t:
    ind=link.index(t)
    print (link[:ind])
```

Output;

```
>>> 
http://blog.test.com/54321
>>>
```

Comment: This will print more than one result, once it gets to the second `'&'`. Use `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex and work for whatever the number between `/`and `&` is.

```
In[2]: import re
In[3]: link = "http://blog.test.com/54321&sa=U&ei=1sTFVJLfOtOC8gW0jIHYCw&ved=0CBMQFjAA"
In[4]: re.findall('^.+/\d+(?=&)',link)
Out[4]: ['http://blog.test.com/54321']
```